# Custom UIView covering UITabBar on iPhone but not iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview, uitabbar, uiwindow

I'm creating a custom uiView that covers the window. It acts kinda like a decoy uiview in a navigation controller. So I had to do it this way to cover the navigation bar.... long story...

Here is how it gets setup.

```
self.searchPopDown.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, self.navigationController.view.frame.size.width, self.navigationController.view.frame.size.height-20);

    self.searchPopDown.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

The 20 is to compensate for the status bar.

Then I simply add the view as a subview to the app window.

```
//this will add the view ontop of a modalViewController and support rotation!
UIWindow* window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
if (!window) {
    window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0];
}

if ([[[window subviews] objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[SVProgressHUD class]]){
    //There is a chance that the window will be the SVProgressHUD in this case we need to get the main window.

    window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0];
}
    [[[window subviews] objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:self.searchPopDown];
```

All of this works great and dandy. However I've noticed something strange. On the iPhone this view will end up being resized to cover the UITabBar at the bottom of my app. But on an iPad it gets resized correctly to compensate for the UITabBar. Any ideas why?

Thanks

=================

Here are some screenshots describing the issue. This is what it looks like when the view loads with the fake view onto of everything. The view shows up (as far as the user is concerned just the view and the buttons on the navbar have changed slightly. When you have searched this fake view disappears revealing the real view below with the search results. ON the ipad the fake view doesn't cover the tab bar. Why doesn't it do this on the iphone also?

[image: iphone tabbar being covered at bottom]

[image: view disappears as expected]

[image: ipad version works correctly]

==========

edit 2
Another weird thing. I'm generating log messages to get what the height of the navigation controller is. It changing by 49 depending on if I display normally or present as a modal view and there is no tab bar.

So the log says 431 should be the correct height. I go into interface builder and setup a simple pink view that's measured at 431 and it looks great :) However when I manually set the size to 431 it doesn't work. I have to set the size to 298 to get this to work correctly ... weird...

See the pink bar? It is literally 431 tall... and the log says that's what my view is.. but it's not :/

[image: pink size comparison]

============

edit:3

I have traced this to the imagebackground with the bubble logo resizing incorrectly...

Comment: Do you have any mockups or screenshots describing what you want and what's actually happening? It will be easier to see the issue that way :)

Comment: Give me a minute or two... I upload the screenshots...

Comment: Hmm... First, why make a full-screen view? It will be easier to just make a small overlay or a popover/modal view. Then, can you check the size of the `self.navigationController.view` view? Couldn't you use the key window's size instead?

Comment: Because this has to cover the navigation bar. If I use a modal view it would cover the tab bar...

Comment: do you really code with those UI colours in Xcode?

Comment: Do you not like my colors? Or my method of implementing them? I'm always open for input. Or maybe you are referring to my theme I have selected? Yes I love the dark theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to check "clip subview" on the parent view that the imageview was in... fixed the problem...

Comment: Yeah... when doing weird stuff like this it's always a pain but beautiful once it works...

Comment: Just a tip, the frame of your view is not the final one during viewDidLoad but it's the final one in the ViewWillAppear. You should have a look at http://subjective-objective-c.blogspot.ch/2011/08/writing-high-quality-view-controller.html for lifeCycle of the UIViewController. Another tip, "don't fight the framework" as Apple engineers say. We all have a long story behind our hacks but it's often a bad idea, hacks have only one goal: stop working with the next iOS release