# superimposing a UIView on top of a ViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uiview, uiviewcontroller

What is the best way to superimpose a UIView on top of a UIViewController that houses a UIWebView?

Hopefully the background of the UIView will be transparent (it's a drawing tool based off of UIBezierPath).

Should I do this based on CALayers?

Comment: All UIViews are based on layers. View controllers themselves are never visible -- only their views are. So it sounds like you just want to display one view above another?

Comment: Take a look at my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645234/custom-uiview-covering-uitabbar-on-iphone-but-not-ipad/12753238#12753238

Comment: Basically you add a sub view to your view controller. If you need to cover the navigation bar my earlier question might help.